# Bathtub boat, is it possible to go forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]

I know nothing would happen when it's just floating. But once I somehow pumped the water to flow out from the shower head, would it keep shooting out water automatically and accelerate the boat endlessly? By the Siphon effect or something? (I know Siphon effect is something different and not applicable here, but anyway)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cartoon 'physics' is not real physics.

Comment: If you use a pump to continuously pump water out then the bathtub can go forward - in fact if the shower head was under the water it would work a similar way to a jetski, but siphon effect won't help as it can only make water drop in height and the water comes out of the showhead above the level of the sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such thing as free energy, friction and gravity would quickly stop the water flow when the pump stopped. Due to the law of conservation of energy, energy cannot be created or destroyed, only transformed or transferred.